# Is there any method for gradient descent that achieves acceleration while moving always in the opposite direction of the gradient?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I'm studying gradient descent methods, in particular Nesterov's methods and others that achieve a better complexity (in terms of access to the gradient oracle) than regular gradient descent. In particular, for a smooth objective, accelerated gradient descent uses $O(1/\sqrt{\epsilon})$ calls to the oracle as opposed to $O(1/\epsilon)$ of regular gradient descent.

I've been reading other methods that accelerate but all of them change the direction of descent. I was wondering if there is some method that always moves following the opposite direction of the gradient and that also only needs $O(1/\sqrt{\epsilon})$ to the gradient oracle.

Answer (score 2):

While the answer to this question is I believe, still unknown, the following papers give an algorithm that improves over the $O(1/\epsilon)$ rate of constant step size gradient descent while always moving in the opposite direction of the gradient: https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.07879 https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.16530